# sprintf raw bytes to string in C?

Tags: c, string, format-specifiers

I am sending some raw bytes over the wire in C (using HTTP). I'm currently doing it like this:

```
// response is a large buffer
int n = 0; // response length
int x = 42; // want client to read x
int y = 43; // and y 

// write a simple HTTP response containing a 200 status code then x and y in binary format
strcpy(response, "HTTP/1.1 200\r\n\r\n");
n += 16; // status line we just wrote is 16 bytes long
memcpy(response + n, &x, sizeof(x));
n += sizeof(x);
memcpy(response + n, &y, sizeof(y));
n += sizeof(y);
write(client, response, n);
```

In JavaScript, I then read this data using code like this:

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
request.open("GET", "/test");
request.onreadystatechange = function() { if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) { console.log(new Int32Array(this.response)) } }
request.send();
```

which prints `[42, 43]` as it should.

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this on the server-side though, e.g.

```
n += sprintf(response, "HTTP/1.1 200\r\n\r\n%4b%4b", &x, &y);
```

Where `%4b` is a made-up format specifier which just says: copy the 4 bytes from that address into the string (which would be "*\0\0\0") Is there a format specifier like the fictional `%4b` that does something like this?

Comment: `sprintf` is used for strings. That is - `char` arrays terminated with `\0`. So no, it is not suitable for arbitrary binary data.

Comment: I don't think so. `sprintf()` is generally intended for creating printable strings, not binary.

Comment: Those `memcpy` calls are going to make your code endian-dependent.

Comment: If you want to send binary data, you should use a well-defined serialization format.

Comment: Thanks all--seems like I can make my code endian-agnostic on the server-side by using `htonl`, that way it will always be big-endian. Then, on the client-side I can use  `new DataView(binaryArrayBuffer).getInt32(0, false)` to make sure the client reads it as big endian.

Comment: There are equivalent [`ntohl`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl) functions and such to "undo" `hton`

Comment: `Is there a format specifier like the fictional %4b` - No, there is not. I think maybe you could use like `%c%c%c%c", ((char*)&x)[3], ((char*)&x)[2], ((char*)&x)[1], ((char*)&x)[0]`.

Comment: Appending `"*\0\0\0"` will terminate the string at the first '\0' - `sprintf()` is not really suitable for this purpose.

Comment: Another note: If you're barfing out raw binary data you should have a `Content-Type:  application/octet-stream` header to indicate this.

Comment: *Then, on the client-side...*  If you control both ends of the connection, just emit it as text and don't worry about endianness or encodings.  The conversion to/from text and the expansion of content from four to a few more bytes won't measurably change any performance, but it will make the data exchange a lot easier to handle in **any** way you want in the future.  `sprintf( line, "%d\r\n", data ); write( client, line, strlen( line ) );` for each 32-bit `int` you want to send.  Parse it any way you want.

Comment: @Clifford, I'm not sure about it. As long as you are sure of the total length (so, calculating the bytes to send without using `strlen()`) I think that `sprintf ()` will write all chars in format, even with all that `/0`s. I should verify it.... I mean, that would be an improper use of sprintf (), but it should work.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni : Sure, but then the trailing nuls are not part of the string, and the title says "string" (even if in fact a string is not what is required).  Moreover I didn't say it couldn't be done, merely that it is not appropriate.  It certainly does not achieve the stated aim of "elegance".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an XY problem, you are asking about how to use `sprintf()` to solve your problem, rather than simply asking how to solve your problem.  YOur actual problem is how to make that code more "elegant".

There is no particular reason to send the data in a single write operation - the network stack buffering will ensure that the data is packetised efficiently:

```
static const char header[] = "HTTP/1.1 200\r\n\r\n" ;
write( client, header, sizeof(header) - 1 ) ;
write( client, &x, sizeof(x) ) ;
write( client, &y, sizeof(y) ) ;
```

Note that X and Y will be written in the native machine byte order, which may be incorrect at the receiver. More generically then:

```
static const char header[] = "HTTP/1.1 200\r\n\r\n" ;
write( client, header, sizeof(header) - 1 ) ;

uint32_t nl = htonl( x ) ;
write( client, &nl, sizeof(nl) ) ;

nl = htonl( y ) ;
write( client, &nl, sizeof(nl) ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a format specifier like the fictional %4b?

No, there is not, and your method is fine. I would suggest using `snprintf` and some check to avoid buffer overflow, adding ex. `static_assert(sizeof(int) == 4, "")` checking that the platform uses big endian and similar environment and error handling and avoiding undefined behavior checks.

That said, you can use `%c` printf specifier multiple times, like `"%c%c%c%c", ((char*)&x)[3], ((char*)&x)[2], ((char*)&x)[1], ((char*)&x)[0]` to print 4 bytes. You can wrap it in macros and do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRI_BYTES_4  "%c%c%c%c"
#define ARG_BYTES_BE_4(var) \
    ((const char*)&(var))[3], \
    ((const char*)&(var))[2], \
    ((const char*)&(var))[1], \
    ((const char*)&(var))[0]

int main() {
    int var = 
        'l' << 24 |
        'a' << 16 | 
        'm' << 8 |
        'e';
    printf("Hello, I am " PRI_BYTES_4 ".\n",
        ARG_BYTES_BE_4(var));
    // will print `Hello, I am lame.`
}
```

Comment: `int var = 'l' << 24 | ...` risks UB as `l` is actually an `int` value, so left shifting it risks overflow and therefore UB.  `uint32_t var = ( ( uint8_t ) 'l' ) << 24 | ...` would be better.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `( ( uint8_t ) 'l' ) << 24` poses the same risks of overflow as `'l' << 24`.  Did you want `( ( uint32_t ) 'l' ) << 24`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  Yeah.  Doh!  I'll plead extremely long day....